# OS X 10.6 Installing Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, rubygems, nokogiri

I am very new to OS X and I don't know anything about compiling, MacPorts, Homebrew, etc. All I want to do is install the Nokogiri gem on OS X.

In Windows, it was as simple as:

```
gem install nokogiri
```

However, when I try this on OS X, I get the following message:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
```

Again, I am not very good with OS X and I have no idea what this means.

Is there an easy way to install Nokogiri without having to mess with MacPorts and other programs I've read about online?

I have XCode 4 installed (some people say XCode is required for this to work), and I'm using Ruby 1.8.7.

Also, I tried installing MacPorts and following the instructions online and I get the following:

```
Derek-MacBook-Pro:~ derek$ sudo port install libxml2 libxslt
Password:
--->  Computing dependencies for libxml2Error: Unable to execute port: can't read "build.cmd": Failed to locate 'make' in path: '/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin' or at its MacPorts configuration time location, did you move it?
To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a Macbook with Leopard, and I gave up on using MacPorts with Rails some time ago. The pain of getting MacPorts to play along with Ruby, gems, etc., yikes. I switched to RVM (Ruby Version Manager), which allows for installing multiple versions of Ruby and gems, so that you can run one app on one version of Ruby plus some versions of gems, and a different app on different versions of ruby and gems.

It's as simple as `rvm install 1.9.2`.

Also, I run FreeBSD on my production machine. When I run RVM, I can keep the same versions of gems running on my Macbook, as are running on my production machine by installing RVM on my production machine the same way I have it on my Macbook.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I needed to install UNIX dev. tools from XCode, which I previously hadn't done. Now the MacPorts command I listed in my question works, and once I successfully got libxml2 installed, I didn't have a problem with the command: `sudo gem install nokogiri`.

Comment: It's real important that your XCode be current. The version that came on the Snow Leopard DVD is broken. Download the current XCode from Apple's XCode site and install that if it's newer. It's a big file so the download will take a while.